# Wordpress menu spacing

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu

I'm working on a WordPress website for a client of mine, and I had to delete and remake some menu links. I believe that some css was set to a specific menu item that I had to remake named "Sellers", because when I remade it, the space between sellers and the center image disappeared. The Sellers button is supposed to be on the right side of the center coldwell banker image. Here is a link to you can see it for yourself:

http://fanpagedirect.com/coldwell/

Does anyone know how to give "Sellers" its own class and add a margin to slide it back over?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/185667)

Comment: Screenshot maybe? what "Sellers"? where is "Sellers"?

Comment: I'm asking how to add a class to a single menu item. I know its possible, because you can add a custom class to the menu options in the admin panel. I'm just not sure how to add it to the stylesheet to where you can call on it from the menu section. I'm not asking anyone to go to my link and solve the whole issue for me... My question is pretty specific.

Comment: Its next to buyers under the menu. It may be tucked behind the menu image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it seems it already has extra class. So you can easily target it.

[image]

you can use class: **Sellerclass**
or ID: **menu-item-391**

To add it, you need to Edit stylesheet, go in `wordpress-intallation/wp-content/themes/theme-name/style.css` and add your class there.

You need to add this:

```
.sellerclass {
margin-left: 222px !important;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I saw that class in the stylesheet, but when I added it to the menu it woulnd't work. I tried using meni-item-391 as well with no luck. =\

Comment: Oh, I needed !important; in there as well. Didn't even think of that... Thanks a bunch Sandro!